# dúvidas quanto a localDB em aplicações MVC C#

Tags: c#

Fiz um post aqui sobre onde a aplicação guarda as informações do template `Register` que vem em aplicações MVC quando criamos um novo projeto. Bem, a pergunta seria a seguinte:

Querendo eu usar essas informações, para trabalhar com elas, teria que abrir o localDB, mas aí vem a questão. Em ambiente web, eu hospedo meu site em um servidor. Quando o usuário se registra lá, eu tenho como pegar essas informações? O nome localDB, dá idéia que a informação está na máquina cliente, sendo assim, não teria como pegar essas informações, certo?

Sei que alguns vão dizer: "crie um cadastro para você e etc", mas eu só quero entender.

Answer (score 2):

## O nome localDB, dá idéia que a informação está na máquina cliente, sendo assim, não teria como pegar essas informações, certo?

Errado. O LocalDb é uma versão do SQL Server que funciona na mesma máquina que a aplicação, ou seja, **no servidor**.

A única peculiaridade dele é que você não precisa instalar uma instância inteira do SQL Server para começar sua aplicação. É um passo a menos, de forma a tornar o desenvolvimento mais simples.

Essa ideia de "local" eu compreendo que traga uma sensação que o banco fica no cliente, mas não é bem isso. Ele tenta ser uma alternativa local de desenvolvimento, assim como é o SQLite.

## Quando o usuário se registra lá, eu tenho como pegar essas informações?

Veja que agora essa pergunta não faz muito sentido. A verdade é que o tipo de acesso a uma base LocalDb é idêntico ao tipo de acesso a um servidor SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Se eu entendi sua pergunta  a resposta é NÃO, o nome do banco não muda nada. se você criar um banco em um servidor SQL e apontar sua aplicação para esse banco, qualquer pessoa que acessar sua aplicação vai usar o mesmo banco.